# Create Pytest-html Report that is Downloadable and Customizable in Python

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, allure, pytest-html

In line with our ongoing task of migrating C# code to Python, specifically in terms of HTML report generation: Do we have any framework on Python that can create a html report of test cases (website quality assurance check via Selenium) with the HTML report and that HTML report outcomes can be customizable - something like Allure Framework, but the HTML report can be downloaded?

Comment: You can use this  : https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html or https://docs.qameta.io/allure-report/frameworks/python/pytest

Comment: Using Pytest-html we can auto generate and download html reports but pytest-html provides very limited customization, and allure provide good customization but the html reports are not downloadable as a standalone html files... We are looking for a library/framework using which we can customize the html report according to our requirements and that html file should be downloadable and can be used as a standalone html file. @DevangSanghani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably host your allure reports in some cloud service like aws and send the link to your users to view the reports.

There's one more that tries to convert allure report into a html version. You can check it [here](https://github.com/MihanEntalpo/allure-single-html-file). I haven't tried it though.

If you do not need allure at all, then there's a [pytest-html-reporter](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html-reporter/) that you can install using `pip install pytest-html-reporter`, which is even more customizable than `pytest-html`. It will give you the feel of the allure report.

Check the screenshots in their github page. I'd say its pretty good but anything more than that, you have to use a lot of css to do your own customizations.[image]

Comment: It doesn't show the ```stdout``` results in the report. Is there anyway to display that?